# Mysql query with multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, left-join, multiple-tables

I hope you can help. I want to do a keyword search on products including multiple tables. But not every product has any entries in each table...

Example

```
table 'product'
id     product_name     description
1      my product       this is my favorite product
2      another item     that is another product
3      blue car         for driving away

table 'keywords'
prod_id    keywords
2          car, product, blue
```

So, now I want to get all products, having 'car' in its 'product_name', 'description' or 'keywords'

Just using a simple mysql query will only have those products as result, which are in both tables:

```
SELECT A.id FROM product A, keywords B WHERE A.ID = B.product_id AND....
```

I tried LEFT JOIN - but that had all three products as result (maybe I did it wrong):

```
SELECT A.id FROM product A LEFT JOIN keywords B ON A.id = B.prod_id AND (A.product_name LIKE '%car%' OR A.description LIKE '%car%' OR B.keywords LIKE '%car%')
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks & regards
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the `AND` in the `LEFT JOIN` instruction instead of `WHERE`. Try

```
SELECT `A.id` FROM product AS `A`
LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords AS `B` ON `A.id` = `B.prod_id`
WHERE (`A.product_name` LIKE '%car%' OR `A.description` LIKE '%car%' OR `B.keywords` LIKE '%car%')
```

Beware that `LIKE '%car%'` will also select `That's my favorite cardigan.`

`RLIKE '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]'` may be better.

---

**Resources:**

Mysql RegExp for RLIKE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/regexp.html

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to use union

```
    select id from product where product_name LIKE '%car%' OR description LIKE '%car%'
    union 
    select prod_id as id from keywords where keywords LIKE '%car%' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using an union:

```
(select id from product where product_name LIKE '%car%' OR description LIKE '%car%')
union 
(select prod_id from keywords where keywords LIKE '%car%' );
```